# Make a navbar always visible (above all)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Is there a way to make the navbar be above all?
Also I´ve been tinkering the main.css Code Igniter but no results.
I don´t know why it uses the header, but there is one in the page I´m working.
Here is an image that shows my problem:

[image: Like this].

Part of the code;

```
<div id="navbar">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="#">Active Link</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        Dropdown 
                        <b class="caret"></b>
                    </a> 
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" data-no-collapse="true">
                        <li class="kopie">
                            <a href="#">Dropdown</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Dropdown Link 1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="active">
                            <a href="#">Dropdown Link 2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Dropdown Link 3</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: This should be in the top, but from unknown reasons the page doesn´t display it in the preview: <header id="header" class="header-front" role="banner">

    <div id="top-menu">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><span><i class="icon-user"></i> <?php echo $_SESSION['sess']['fullname']; ?></span></li>
                    <li> | <?php echo anchor('logout', '<i class="icon-power-off"></i> Logout'); ?></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> <!--/#top-menu-->

Answer (score 0):

I can't see what your current CSS is, and what de code of the div or section below is... But you should add this to your CSS. And try to keep the z-indexs below 100.

```
#navbar {position:relative; z-index:50;}          /* Navbar is on top */
#idOfContentHere {position: relative; z-index:0}  /* Your content is not on top */
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the mess, I´m kinda new posting in stackoverflow.
This is part of the main.css refering to the navbar:

```
.navbar-default {
background-color: #fff;
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#FFF, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
background: -o-linear-gradient(#FFF, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#FFF, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
background: linear-gradient(#FFF, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)); /* Standard syntax */
border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
border: 0;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2);
box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2);
overflow: hidden;
}
.navbar-default .first a {
  border-radius: 0 0 0 5px;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  margin-right: 50px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 78px;
  background-image: url("img/logo-uanl.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
  background-position: 0 50%;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li {
  margin-left: 1px;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  padding: 20px 25px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 18px;
  color: #666;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a > i {
  display: inline-block;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li.active > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li.active:focus > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li.active:hover > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li:hover > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li:focus > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li.active > a:focus,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li.active:focus > a:focus,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li.active:hover > a:focus,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li:hover > a:focus,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li:focus > a:focus {
background-color: #73AF01;
color: #fff;
}
```

Header looks like this:

```
#header
{
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 120%;
z-index: 100000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it... the problem was the "hidden" property in: overflow. For future incidents like this one, I recomend the use of the property "visible" or simply don´t use "overflow".